# allocate memory for multidimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to multiply arrays A,B. These arrays are of fixed size. I infer their sizes with templates. Now I want to allocate some memory for C which is equal A*B. My problem is that when I do (N=3,L=5)

`int (*C)[N][L] = new int[N][L]`

i get

`error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[5]’ to ‘int (*)[3][5]’ in initialization`.

I made a workaround but still wonder how can I do it without the workaround.

```
template<int N, int K>
struct matrix {
  int array[N][K];
};

template<int N, int K, int L>
int (&multiply(int (&A)[N][K], int (&B)[K][L]))[N][L] {

  matrix<N,L> *mat = new matrix<N,L>();
  int (&C)[N][L] = mat->array;

  return C;
}

int main() {
  int A[3][4];
  int B[4][5];

  int (&C)[3][5] = multiply(A, B);
}
```

you can make other solutions with `typedef` or `reinterpreted_cast` but why you need them? It is like a failure in c++ itself, the language failed to delivered what was promised. It is similar to generics in Java. You think that containers like `List<T>` would know better but they follow the same faulty way with casting and `@SuppressWarnings`.

Comment: Your "workaround" looks like a memory leak to me. If you are making a matrix class, give it correct value semantics. Just implement an old-fashioned multiplication operator that takes two matrices and returns a new one.

Comment: What about simply using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)?

Comment: Something like `std::array<std::array<int, L>, N>` would be more optimal.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious A matrix class using a single array would be more optimal. There are pre-conditions that can be maintained at compile time, for instance, the dimensions of matrices have to be right for multiplication, addition, etc. Also, array of array's is not guaranteed to store all of the sub-elements contiguously (although in practice I can't imagine why an implementation wouldn't do that.)

Comment: @juanchopanza don't be hard on memory leaks. I prepare example usage of templates for students. The other thing is I can use no loops only recursion.
I am just looking for justification why can't you `new int[5][6]` even though it is type available in c++.

Comment: @lord.didger Oh I see. Well, `new[]` returns a pointer, e.g. `new int[42]` returns `int*`. So `new int[A][B]` returns pointer to `int[B]`. I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with

```
int (*C)[N][L] = new int[N][L];
```

is that `new T[n]` returns a pointer to `T`. The fact that an array has been allocated is not visible in the return type. So the expression `new int[N][L]` returns a pointer to size-`L` array of `int`. That is the type you need on the LHS:

```
int (*C)[L] = new int[N][L];
```